# Anything similar to folium in Julia?

Tags: julia, geomap

I am interested in plotting some data on a map using Julia. Is there currently a library similar to Python's folium that could do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a native julia library, but you can call Python from Julia via [PyCall.jl](https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl).

A related plotting package put out by the same developer is [PyPlot](https://github.com/stevengj/PyPlot.jl). An examples gist for PyPlot can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/gizmaa/7214002).